# MS Access Enter Parameter ID upon Report Generation from Filter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a text field with a button that filters by a keyword in a form.

```
Private Sub Command93_Click()
Me.Filter = "(Review Like '*" & Me.Text94 & "*')OR (Status Like '*" & Me.Text94 & "*')"
Me.FilterOn = True
Me.Requery

End Sub
```

I then have a button that generates the report from that filter.

```
Private Sub Filter_Click()

DoCmd.OpenReport "rptName", acViewPreview, , Me.Filter

End Sub
```

The problem is that whenever I hit this button to generate the report, I get a pop up box asking me to Enter Parameter ID and it is asking this for review. If I take the review criteria out (by the way I have many more fields I just used review and status to illustrate the example) then the report generates without any pop up box. The review is part of a notinlist event which opens another form and stores that info in a table review, if that is relevant at all. The report will still generate when I click ok and leave the Enter Parameter ID box blank but I'd like to somehow bypass it for two reasons - the first being the fact that I need other people who are not familiar with access to be able to use it and the second is the idea that if I learn what is causing it I can understand the way access works better. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your report have a field called Review? If not, you either need to change the recordsource of the report so it is joined with the table that has review, or change your filter so it refers to the field that the report has.

Comment: The report has a field tblReview_Review that has the same information. I can change the filter so it refers to tblReview_Review and it fixes the parameter ID for generating the report, but then asks for parameter ID on the filter button instead. The same thing happened when I changed the recordsource to the review in the report, producing a parameter ID box in the filter click event instead of the generate report click event.

Comment: I reckon you should copy the sql for the report into the query design window and add the filter as a WHERE statement, this will more easily show the problems. If you post the sql and the filter, it may be possible to say more.